# In Projectile Motion, will the initial velocity ALWAYS equal the final velocity? What about in the case of Y not equaling Yo?

Tags: kinematics, projectile

This questions assumes that air resistance is negligible.

I know that in some cases the initial and final velocity do equal each other. However, I am confused as to when that applies, in what cases. It seems logical that the initial velocity and final velocity only equal when the projectile is parabolic and symmetric (where y = yo). I have nothing to support this.

One case I am concerned about is when the initial height is not equal to the landing height (Yo does not equal Y), and the projectile is shot at an angle theta.

In that case, will the initial and final magnitudes of the velocities be the same?

In what cases does the initial velocity not equal the final velocity?

Comment: If you shoot straight down then the velocity will increase due to gravity.

Comment: If the initial vertical velocity is upwards then yes, the initial and final velocity magnitude will be equal, where "final" is when the height is back to the height it was launched at.

Answer (score 1):

Projectile motion is defined as the motion of a particle under the influence of gravity only. This means that the horizontal component of the force on the particle is zero and hence its acceleration is also zero. This means that the horizontal component of the velocity remains unchanged throughout the duration of the motion.
Also, it so happens that the vertical component of the velocity at the end at the beginning turn out to be equal in magnitude since the particle takes equal time going up and coming down. Thus, the vertical components at the start and at the end are equal.
Thus is true for any two points that are at an equal height from the ground. If you draw a line parallel to the ground, then the two points where it intersects the trajectory of the particle will have equal magnitudes of velocity. 
If the heights are unequal, the magnitudes will be in unequal as well

Comment: I have a question to follow this up. Will the horizontal velocity always remain the same, assuming no air resistance and such? In other words, are there cases where this would not apply?

Comment: The horizontal component will ALWAYS remain the same, since no force acts in that direction. For a velocity to change, a non zero force is required IN THAT DIRECTION(unless you want to deal with massless objects). So even in general, if a particle is under the influence of some force, then you can be sure that the velocity of the particle perpendicular to the direction of force will not change.

Comment: I see. This makes much more sense. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

MaxW, your intuition is correct. For ideal conditions, initial velocity equals final velocity if, but only if, initial and final elevations (Y) are equal. In fact during flight, the velocity on the way up at a given elevation (Yn) is the same as the velocity on the way down at that same elevation (Yn).

Comment: This makes sense. I did not want to depend purely on my logic though, for there are people who like you who can correct my logic if it is incorrect!

Answer (score 0):

In classical mechanics the laws of conservation of energy require that for a projectile motion where the heights of the start and end point are equal the velocities are also equal in magnitude. That is because the sum of the potential and kinetic energy for the body must remain the same. 
$$U_0 + T_0 = U_1 + T_1$$
where $U$ is the potential energy and $T$ is the kinetic energy

We know that the potential energy is $$U = hgM$$
where $h$ is the height (or in your case the position in the Y direction), $g$ is the gravitational acceleration and $M$ is the mass of the projectile.

and the kinetic energy is $$T = \frac{1}{2} MV^2
$$

where $M$ is again the mass of the projectile and $V$ is the velocity.

If we substitute the equations for the potential and kinetic energies in the first equation we get
$$\frac{1}{2}MV_0 + h_0gM = \frac{1}{2}MV_1 + h_1gM
$$

The masses cancel out and with a bit of algebra for the final velocity we get:
$$V_1 = \sqrt{V_0^2 - 2g(h_1-h_0))}
$$
Notice that there are cases where this equation has no real solution - when the stuff under the square root is negative. That is because there would be not enough initial kinetic energy to compensate the gain in potential energy.

If you are interested in the actual change in velocity:
$$\Delta V = V_0-V_1
$$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the conditions mentioned you are correct, you are correct. Initial and final magnitudes of the velocities are the same. And initial velocity is NOT equal the final velocity.

In other answers, initial speed equal final speed. Speed, a scalar without direction, is the magnitudes of velocity. But since the velocities, speed of something in a given direction, have different directions technically the velocities are not equal. Example, a car going 50 mph East and a car going 50 mph North do not have the equal velocities.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/425883)